# Bag with non-integer count Map<Object, BigDecimal>

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I need to map objects to their counts, as I would with a [bag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) or [multi-set](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) but with a `BigDecimal` count rather than an whole number.

So for example, I might add 2.3 kg of sugar, 4.5 kg of salt, and another 1.4 kg of sugar. Then if I I `get` the sugar, it will return 3.7. If I `get` the salt it will return 4.5.

I can write one easily enough, but can is there an existing implementation I can use? and what is this data-structure called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use new `Map` api [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) introduced in `java-8`:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> counts = new HashMap<>();

counts.merge("sugar", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.3), BigDecimal::add);
counts.merge("salt", BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5), BigDecimal::add);
counts.merge("pepper", BigDecimal.valueOf(1.8), BigDecimal::add);
counts.merge("sugar", BigDecimal.valueOf(1.4), BigDecimal::add);

System.out.println(counts); // {pepper=1.8, salt=4.5, sugar=3.7}
```

Comment: Great answer. Would be even better if you used the values mentioned in the example. :-)

Comment: That is useful - just what I wanted. It's a shame we're still on Java 7 where I work.

Answer (score 1):

What about a custom HashMap? Can't think on a simpler solution

In Java 7:

```
class Bag extends HashMap<Object, BigDecimal> {
    public void add(Object key, BigDecimal value){
        if (containsKey(key))
            value = get(key).add(value);
        put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Or, in Java 8:

```
class Bag extends HashMap<Object, BigDecimal> {
    public void add(Object key, BigDecimal value){
        merge(key, value, BigDecimal::add);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Bag bag = new Bag();
bag.add("Sugar", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.3));
bag.add("Salt",  BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5));
bag.add("Sugar", BigDecimal.valueOf(1.4));
System.out.println(bag.get("Sugar")); // Prints 3.7
```

Comment: Do not use the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor. Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` instead. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) even says so (#3). That will change result of your solution to `3.7`, as it should be.

Comment: In Java 8, the body of `add()` should be `compute(key, (k, v) -> (v == null ? value : v.add(value)));`

Comment: It "could" be, not necessarily "should" :)

Comment: It's better, requiring only one map "lookups", instead of 2-3 (`containsKey`, `get`, and `put`).

Comment: In Java 8 it would be even simpler (as Anton Balaniuc suggested): `merge(k, v, BigDecimal::add);` but I'm not sure on actual performance gain, `merge` and `compute` surely need to do "lookups" anyway

Comment: In Java 8 it should be even simpler, no `merge` or `compute` needed, I think -- `getOrDefault()` should do the job, no?

Comment: @avysk No, in this particular case we want to sum the old value with the new value provided

Comment: @Oneiros Yes, I understand. I mean in the body of `add` method to write something like `put(key, getOrDefault(key, BigDecimal.ZERO).add(value))` (Though yeah, there's no reason not to use `merge` for that.)

Comment: @avysk Oh I see. Yeah, that would work too of course. However the `merge` approach still looks simpler to me

Comment: @Oneiros Yes, I agree.